# How to retrieve selected option value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

Hi guys new to laravel here! i am using selected option drop down list The First Select contains the countries and the second one has the states, now When i try to store the in database i am not getting the proper selected state instead i am always getting the first state in the second select Option!! i am using query Builder.

> This is How i am retrieving  Countries and states

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{


$country = DB::table("countries")->where("id",$request->daira);
$state = DB::table("states")->where("country_id",$request->daira);
$daira = $country->get()->first()->name;
$impact = $state->get()->first()->commune;

dd($impact);
}
```

> **Note**: dd($impact); Should be retrieving the selected state, instead it's retrieving the first value on the Selection List

So my Question is How do i get it to retrieve The proper Selected state !? Hope my question is clear Thanks in Advance.

**Updated:**
In the First Select option I have Countries name and in the second option i have 
states each country has maximum 3 states, let's say Country A has 3 States A1,A2 and A3 And i want to select  State A2 from the select option Value and instead of getting A1 by default like my case in the Question

> **Updated:** I Am using VueJs

This is The form code

```
<template>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
        <select name="direction" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Selctionner Direction</option>
            <option value="ENERGIE">ENERGIE</option>
            <option value="HYDRAULIQUE">HYDRAULIQUE</option>
            <option value="ENVIRONNEMENT">    ENVIRONNEMENT</option>
            <option value="AMENAGEMENT">AMENAGEMENT</option>
            <option value="P.T.T">P.T.T</option>
            <option value="TOURISME">TOURISME</option>
            <option value="TRANSPORT">TRANSPORT</option>
            <option value="TRAVAUX PUBLICS">TRAVAUX PUBLICS</option>
            <option value="EDUCATION">EDUCATION</option>
            <option value="ENSEIGNEMENT SUPERIEUR">ENSEIGNEMENT SUPERIEUR</option>
            <option value="URBANISME">URBANISME</option>
            <option value="FORMATION PROFESSIONNELLE">FORMATION PROFESSIONNELLE</option>
            <option value="SANTE">SANTE</option>
            <option value="JEUNESSE-SPORTS CULTURE">JEUNESSE-SPORTS CULTURE</option>
            <option value="PROTECTION SOCIALE">PROTECTION SOCIALE</option>
            <option value="INFRASTRUCTURES ADMINISTRATIVES">INFRASTRUCTURES ADMINISTRATIVES</option>
            <option value="HABITAT">HABITAT</option>
            <option value="COMMERCE">COMMERCE</option>
            <option value="LOGEMENT">LOGEMENT</option>
            <option value="LOCAUX A USAGE PROFESSIONNELE">LOCAUX A USAGE PROFESSIONNELE</option>
            <option value="FORET">FORET</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Selctionner Daira:</label>
            <select name="daira" class='form-control' v-model='country' @change='getStates()'>
                <option value='0' >Select Country</option>
                <option v-for='data in countries' :value='data.id'>{{ data.name }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Selctionner Commune:</label>
            <select name="impact" class='form-control' v-model='state'>
                <option value='0' >Select State</option>
                <option v-for='data in states' :value='data.id'>{{ data.commune }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label >Intitule :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="intitule" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And this is My Script

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        data(){
            return {
                country: 0,
                countries: [],
                state: 0,
                states: []
            }
        },
        methods:{
            getCountries: function(){
                axios.get('/api/getCountries')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        this.countries = response.data;
                    }.bind(this));

            },
            getStates: function() {
                axios.get('/api/getStates',{
                    params: {
                        country_id: this.country
                    }
                }).then(function(response){
                    this.states = response.data;
                }.bind(this));
            }
        },
        created: function(){
            this.getCountries()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: examine what is coming in from request

`dd($request->all());`

Comment: it retrieve 4 values from my form

Comment: @MohamedMidou What is a `commune`? Is it state name?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya yes it's a state name

Comment: @MohamedMidou can you try `dd($state);` . Right state retriving?

Comment: `it retrieve 4 values from my form` what are the four values. past the output here

Comment: Also try `$request->input('daira');`

Comment: @EmekaMbah $request->input('daira');  dose the half job it's retrieve the proper selected states but only the id i want get the name

Comment: if you want  the  name then you need to change value  on your form

Comment: @EmekaMbah i need to retrieve the id from the value form and then using query builder i store it by  name ?

Comment: Yes all you need is the right ID, which you then use in your query

Comment: But your query does n't look good dough ..I will provide an answer since I cant type here

Comment: @EmekaMbah yeah the right id that i selected from the states option value then use the id to get the name of that state from database and store it with the name

Comment: @EmekaMbah post your answer it might help

Comment: @MohamedMideou you need to use ajax for this problem. OR IF you can retrieved state id from states drop-down then pass id in controller.

Answer (score 0):

can you post the result of `dd($request->all())` ?

---

assuming your select name is daira and impact, you should be able to get the posted value with this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $daira = $request->daira;
    $impact = $request->impact;
}
```

Comment: This answers half my question because that's code retrieve only the id of the selected value i want the "name" to be stored in database not "id"

Comment: So you want to store the name instead of the ID? then you should make the select box with the name as value, not the ID, like so:

<select name="daira">
   <option value="abc">abc</option>
</select>

or with blade

{{ Form::select('daira',\App\Daira::pluck('name','name')) }}

Answer (score 0):

I understand your issue first state returns because of when you passed country id it returns all the state related this country.

So that you need to pass state Id from state drop-down.

```
  <select name="impact">
       <option value="id">{{ STATE NAME }} </option>
  </select>
```

And then you need to pass that state id in controller.

```
   $state = DB::table("states")->where("id",$request->impact);
```

Comment: @MohamedMidou you can directly passed imapct in the state query. I have updated answer.

Comment: Your vue js is perfect. Now you can retrieved state using state id.

Comment: I am retrieving the state id and with that id i wanna get the name of that state id

Answer (score 0):

Hope you understand your queries
I assume `$request->daira` is country ID

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //here you selected a country with provided country ID 
    //this returns Query Builder object
    $country = DB::table("countries")->where("id",$request->daira);

    //here you are returning all the states where the country_id is 
    //the provided country ID
    //Note that this returns all the states (Query Builder object)
    $state = DB::table("states")->where("country_id",$request->daira);

    //You return `Illuminate\Support\Collection` then you got the first item 
    //from collection
    $daira = $country->get()->first()->name;

    //You returned all the states `Illuminate\Support\Collection`
    //and you picked the first state from the collection, 
    //which is likely the first item in your
    //form select field options
    $impact = $state->get()->first()->commune;

    dd($impact);
}
```

Because you didn't specify state_id, you will always get lists of all the states under the given country.
I assume table relationship is Country -> hasMany -> State

You need to add state_id as constraint, so only one state is picked

`$state_id = $request->state`
I assume you have state in your form

```
$state = DB::table("states")
->where("country_id",$request->daira)
->where('id', $state_id)
->first();

$impact = $state->commune
```

Comment: I understand this can you provide me with a solution so that i don't pick up the first state and instead i pick up the proper selected state thanks :)